# How can I evaluate bash arguments in a string once variables have changed

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

not really sure how to describe this but I'll do my best to explain what I'm doing. I've been `BASH`ing my head against the wall trying to figure out how to pass a string ex. `{command:$1}` into a script and have it populate the `$1` with it's respective value.

What i'm trying to attempt is converting my `lsof` output to json, grabbing the columns I want after parsing with `awk` and formatting, setting key, values with my script.

### My Script

```
#!/bin/bash

FORMAT=$1
(
IFS=' ';
while read line; do
    set -- $line;
    echo $FORMAT
done
)
```

### My command line call

```
lsof -Pn | grep LISTEN | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$8,$9}' | ~/.scripts/json "{command:\$1,pid:\$2,user:\$3,fd:\$4,protocol:\$5:\$6,host:\$7}"
```

### My return

```
{command:$1,pid:$2,user:$3,fd:$4,protocol:$5:$6,host:$7}
```

if I remove the forward slashes I get

```
{command:,pid:,user:,fd:,protocol::,host:}
```

### What I'm expecting

```
{command:webstorm,pid:5270,user:daviddiefenderfer,fd:142u,protocol:IPv4:TCP,host:127.0.0.1:6942}
```

I'm not sure what exactly is happening but I would love to understand, my guess is that the variables `$[1-7]` are being evaluated before they get into the while loop, where there is no values.

Answer (score 1):

You are reinventing the wheel (and incorrectly). Use `jq` to generate your JSON.

```
 lsof -Pn | 
   awk '/LISTEN/ {print $1,$2,$3,$4, $5,$8,$9}' |
   jq -R 'split(" ") |
         {
           command: .[0],
           pid: .[1],
           user: .[2],
           fd: .[3],
           protocol: "\(.[4]):\(.[5])", 
           host: .[6]
         }'
```

If you version of `jq` supports regular expressions, you can drop the call to `awk` as well:

```
lsof -Pn | jq -R '
  select(match("LISTEN")) |
  [splits("  *")] |
  {
    command: .[0],
    pid: .[1],
    user: .[2],
    fd: .[3],
    protocol: "\(.[4]):\(.[7])", 
    host: .[8]
  }'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing awk's `$1, $2, ...` field accessors with the shell's `$1, $2, ...` positional parameters. Also, a pipe does not set positional parameters, it just provides the output from the left-hand side as the input to the right-hand side.

Don't forget that JSON requires string values to be quoted, including object property names:

```
json=$(
    lsof -Pn | grep LISTEN \
    | awk '
        BEGIN {template = "{\"command\":\"%s\",\"pid\":\"%s\",\"user\":\"%s\",\"fd\":\"%s\",\"protocol\":\"%s:%s\",\"host\":\"%s\"}\n"}
        {printf template, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $8, $9}
    '
)
~/.scripts/json "$json"
```